# Avoid cast in generic factories

Tags: java, generics

Suppose I have a class structure looking like this:

```java
public abstract class Interval<I extends Interval<?>> {
    public static final IntervalFactory<? extends Interval<?>> factory = null;

    // some variables and methods
}

public class Week extends Interval<Week> {
    public static final IntervalFactory<Week> factory = new WeekFactory();
    
    // some variables and methods
}

public interface IntervalFactory<I extends Interval> {
    I containing(LocalDate date);
    List<I> containing(LocalDate startDate, LocalDate endDate);
}

public class WeekFactory implements IntervalFactory<Week> {
    @Override
    public Week containing(LocalDate date) {
        // implementation
    }

    @Override
    public List<Week> containing(LocalDate startDate, LocalDate endDate) {
        // implementation
    }
}
```

Now I have a class that uses those intervals and factories:

```
public class SomeClass<I extends Interval<?>> {
    private final IntervalFactory<I> intervalFactory;

    public DistributorForSlowQuantifier() {
        this.intervalFactory = (IntervalFactory<I>) I.factory;
    }
    
    public Map<I, Double> distribute(double value) {
        // implementation
    }
}
```

Is this the right way of approaching the problem if a class needs to create instances from a type variable?

Is there a way around the cast in the `SomeClass` constructor?

The obvious things don't work - having a wildcard as the type parameter of intervalFactory in `SomeClass` loses all the type information, the factories are static, so I cannot use `I` as a type parameter, and if I don't mark them as static, I need an instance of I to access the factory...

The cast is absolutely safe, as long as Interval implementations choose the "corresponding" factory, but it still feels... wrong.

Comment: Why is `Interval` generic?

Comment: I put together a Span class many year ago. It seems similar to what you are doing here: https://sourceforge.net/p/tus/code/HEAD/tree/tjacobs/util/Span.java

Comment: `I.factory` is `null` (`I.factory` is just an obfuscated way of saying `Interval.factory`). The cast is the least of your worries.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The cast in the `SomeClass` constructor doesn't even work.  It'll always use `Interval.factory`, whether or not that corresponds to the kind of factory you want.  `I.factory` does not do what you think.

By far the most common and sensical approach: to pass in the appropriate factory to the constructor.  You can add some syntactic sugar around this with static imports  and static factory methods to make it look like e.g. `new DistributorForSlowQuantifier(days())` or the like.  There are other, much more convoluted and messy workarounds, but all things considered, they're worse.